# Need help to get updated reports in Visual Studio have been setup as linked reports to update direct to linked report

Tags: reporting-services

I have just moved into a new company and the people who setup their reports set them up under projects and then created reports.   Using Visual Studio they then updated to the server, created a linked report to sub folders via internet explorer interface.

I have now found that to update any of these reports, I have to update them to the project location and then delete the old report and create a new linked report.

I am hoping that there is a gap in my knowledge and there is another way to do this.   Alternatively is there a way I can move the reports to their respective folders.   I do not have access to the reportserver to create folders but can apply to IT to get these done.

Would love some help so I do not spend days updating most of these reports.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly they are developing the reports in visual studio and using the deploy function to upload them to the reporting server. They then create a linked report using the web-based report manager interface so that the report is the accessible from another location.

I haven't tested it using the auto-deployment feature of visual studio, but at least if you update the main report then all linked reports will now be the new version as well. So you should just be able to deploy from visual studio and have all of the old linked reports work as well. Only if the auto-deployment process involves deleting the original report before uploading will the linked reports be broken. As long as it is a simple update/replace operation it will be fine.

If it is actually deleting the reports during deployment and the linked reports stop functioning (giving an error something like "the report link is no longer valid") then you don't actually have to fully delete and recreate the linked report. You can go to the properties of the linked report and update the link location so that it will no point to the proper report again (tested on 2008 R2). This will save you from having to redo all of the security and subscriptions that the linked report may have.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually fix linked reports after deleting and redeploying report.

Check out the `Catalog` table in the `ReportServer` database; you have to update the `LinkSourceID` of the linked report with the ID of newly deployed report. Something like this:

```sql
update Catalog
set LinkSourceID = '1370C4D7-7F92-4D6A-BD54-30F1E6913899'
where Type = 4
and name like 'FAR%'
```